# SQL Server standard circular replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, mirroring

As far as i know, SQL Server standard edition supports only 1 mater and other becomes its replica, like Master---> Slave mirroring or replication,

Does it also supports Circular replication? like master<--->Master replication? or it only supports one way replication

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 - Standard Edition supports the following replications types:

| Feature | Enterprise | Standard | Web | Express with Advanced Services | Express |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Heterogeneous subscribers | Yes | Yes | No | No | No |
| Merge replication | Yes | Yes | Yes 1 | Yes 1 | Yes 1 |
| Oracle publishing | Yes | No | No | No | No |
| Peer to peer transactional replication | Yes | No | No | No | No |
| Snapshot replication | Yes | Yes | Yes 1 | Yes 1 | Yes 1 |
| SQL Server change tracking | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Transactional replication | Yes | Yes | Yes 1 | Yes 1 | Yes 1 |
| Transactional replication to Azure | Yes | Yes | No | No | No |
| Transactional replication updatable subscription | Yes | Yes | No | No | No |

<sup>***Reference:** [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2019 | Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver16#Replication) (Microsoft Learn | SQL)*</sup>

The replication types supported by the Standard Edition do not include the **peer-to-peer replication** which is what you might be interested in:

> Peer-to-peer replication provides a scale-out and high-availability solution by maintaining copies of data across multiple server instances, also referred to as nodes. Built on the foundation of transactional replication, peer-to-peer replication propagates transactionally consistent changes in near real-time. This enables applications that require scale-out of read operations to distribute the reads from clients across multiple nodes. Because data is maintained across the nodes in near real-time, peer-to-peer replication provides data redundancy, which increases the availability of data.
> ...
> ...
> ...
> [image: Microsoft SQL Server Peer to Peer Replication with 3 Nodes in different locations Los Angeles, London, Taipei]

<sup>***Reference:** [Peer-to-Peer - Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/peer-to-peer-transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver16) (Microsoft Learn | SQL)*</sup>

#### Answering Your Question

> **Does it also supports Circular replication? like master<--->Master replication? or it only supports one way replication**

- Microsoft SQL Server 2019 - **Standard Edition does not support circular replication**. (You will have to use a one-way replication with Standard Edition)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2019 - **Enterprise Edition does support a form of circular replication** (aka peer-to-peer replication)

Comment: what about always on cluster ? as it has realtime database mirroring? and it supports 2 nodes i think? actually i want 2 node cluster , to have HA and DR

Comment: @Farhan AlwaysOn Availability Groups are primarily an Enterprise-only feature, and never have a bi-directional master to master topology. Also they roughly have the same amount of *real-time* synchronization as Transactional Replication. Furthermore, you should always state which version of SQL Server you're using, as that affects what is applicable to you, including in this above answer.

Comment: @Farhan Please add your exact requirements to your question and I will update my answer. Stackexchange is not your typical thread based ***Keep on asking***  community, but a ***Ask one Question, get multiple answers*** type of community. Consider looking at [ask] and [help]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Standard Edition supports [Bidirectional Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/bidirectional-transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver16)

> Bidirectional transactional replication is a specific transactional
> replication topology that allows two servers to exchange changes with
> each other: each server publishes data and then subscribes to a
> publication with the same data from the other server.

. . .

> In SQL Server 2005 (9.x) and later versions, this topology is also
> supported by peer-to-peer transactional replication, but bidirectional
> replication can provide improved performance.

And Merge replication which supports propagating changes from the publisher to subscriber, and subscriber to publisher.

Comment: I didn't realize that. I had it in the back of my head, but couldn't find the info.